# Proguard rule for determinate progress bar UI animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, proguard

In my application when the proguard rule (minifyEnabled true) is enabled, the circular progress bar with download icon animation doesn’t stop. The functionality downloading the data is working as expected. On click of the downloaded file it opens but the download animation with the progress bar never ends. I checked the `proguard-rules.pro` file for the progress bar. Yet, I cannot make it work. When the minifyEnabled is disabled everything works as expected.

Expecting once the data is downloaded the progress bar should disappear. Proguard rules for progressbar UI